# Installing Salamander along side Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

When the Caveat Box comes up (where it should ask whether I want to install Salamander ALONG SIDE WINDOWS 8), I get only 2 selections:
It says that no other O/S is installed on this hard drive (it is the only hard drive installed) and that I can either:
-- erase the disk and install Ubuntu (warning, all existing data will be erased)     or
-- something else.

/// If I do choose, Something Else, the partition box clearly shows the existing Win 8 partition, along with an "Unknown" labled mfstres flagged partition, a recovery partition, an EFI partition, and a "Push Button Reset" partition --- all labeled primary partitions.

gParted and Disk utilities also show the same.

Partition Order is:
sda1 = unk file system  ----- label         120MB    msftres flag
sda2 = ntfs             Recovery            400MB    diag
sda3 = fat32            ESP-EFI             300MB    boot
sda4 = ntfs             Gateway            914.44 GB   msftdata
sda5 = ntfs             Push Button Reset   16.27 GB   diag

Answer (score 0):

Boot [`gparted-live-disk`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php),split the 914.44GB partition and try to install ubuntu on one of the splitted partitions.